# Create Main View Counter with viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, swift

I need to create a Main View counter, which will count every time i come back from a different view to the Main View.
I have put the counter into the viewWillAppear method. This works fine as long as I switch to the second view, which I have implemented with a SecondViewController.

If I want to switch to a second Storyboard View, which is controlled by the same ViewController an error will occur. 
Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value.

The button "show second storyboard view" which will connect the Main View and the Second Storyboard View is made at the Main.storyboard only (no code at ViewController written).

[Here a picture of the Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRVr4.png)

I have only programmed the dismiss function of the second storyboard.

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {

     let secondViewController = SecondViewController()

     var appearanceCounter = 0

     @IBOutlet weak var counterLabel: UILabel!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
     }

     override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         appearanceCounter += 1

         counterLabel.text = String(appearanceCounter)
     }

     @IBAction func showSecondViewPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
         secondViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
         secondViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .flipHorizontal

 //        present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

         show(secondViewController, sender: nil)

     }

     @IBAction func backWithSequeUwindPressed(unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

         self.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve

     }
     @IBAction func backWithIBActionPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

         self.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
         self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

     }
 }
```

The counter should handle both situations. It should count when I navigate back from the SecondView and also from the SecondStoryboardView. How can I implement a proper counter? What kind of mistake have I made?

Comment: I do not understand how your controllers are linked and which originate from code and which from storyboard. Maybe it's a good idea to include an image of your storyboard.

Comment: @KlixxOne I have a added a print screen - I hope it will make it clearer. Thanks for your help

Comment: Where exactly does this error occur? Can you highlight it in the code? Are the yellow and blue views both controlled by the same viewcontrollers?

Comment: I have updated the picture - there you can see where the error occurs. Yes exactly, they are controlled both by the same view controller. - I think this is why the problem occur, but I do not know how to get around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem here is, that the yellow view is controlled by the same controller as the blue one.

On creation of the blue one the interface builder takes care of linking the counter label to its variable in the accompanying code.
For the yellow one there is no such label and therefore nothing is being linked to the `counterLabel` variable, thus being nil when `viewDidAppear` for the yellow one gets run.
Because IBOutlets are force unwrapped optionals (notice the ! after the declaration) by default this access crashes the app.

The proper way to deal with this situation is to actually have 2 different controllers in code for their counterpart in the interface builder.
Also another option, if that’s not possible for you, would be to exchange the `!` for a `?`.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Then accept the answer so others know this topic is solved :-)